# jQuery what instead $(this).parent().children()

Tags: javascript, jquery, parent, children

Just a quick example:

```
<p>
    <span class="example"></span>
    <input type="text" name="e_name" id="e_id />
</p>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('input').click(function(){
        $(this).parent().children('span').text('Suprise!');
    }
</script>
```

What can I use instead parent().children()?

I think it's a bit inelegant piece of code.
Is any function i.e : $(this).fun('span').text('just better'); ??

Comment: Thanks for making a very readable question so I didn't have to click on 3 different answers, not knowing what was inside.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

```
$(this).siblings('span').text('Suprise!');
```

Comment: I definitely like `.siblings`, hadn't even thought of that function, great answer.

Comment: `$(this).siblings()` will ignore itself, so if you want to target children including itself, `parent().children()` is still neat.

Answer (score 7):

`$(this).siblings('span').text('Surprise!');`

Would be the equivalent without traversing up the DOM and then back down (I mean, it still does it, but at least you're not doing it manually).

Answer (score 4):

Slightly more elegant is `.prev()`

```
$(this).prev('span').text('Surprise!');
```

you can read more about it here: [Prev](http://api.jquery.com/prev/)

edit: read the markup backwards, prev is better, not next.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$(this).prev('span').text('Surprise!');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("span.example",$(this).parent()).text('Suprise!');
```